# How to update value of a Model's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have an database items and two items in it. They have column named "popularity", that I set to 0.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible .. :popularity, ..

  before_create :default_values
  def default_values
    if self.popularity.nil? == true || self.popularity.blank? == true || self.popularity.class != Integer
      self.popularity = 0
    end
  end
```

How to change this value via code\console and save it?
I tried

```
  Item.find(1).popularity = 1
  Item.save
```

But it didn't save my val. Whats wrong?

Comment: for brevity's sake: `Item.find(1).tap{|item| item.popularity = 1 }.save`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

here is the solution

```
item = Item.find(1)
item.popularity = 1
item.save
```

Comment: no yours is not the same because you were running the save on class which should not be the case as you are changing only one instance of it.

Comment: but when i write Item.find(1).save it didn't save val too

Comment: save update the database...but in the process which you were following you assigned the value of popularity first time and in second step when you ran the above command `Item.find(1).save` it retrieved the first document again and it has the old value because the new value was not updated in first step.

Answer (score 2):

```
item = Item.first
item.popularity = 1
item.save
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Item.update(1, popularity: 1)
```

- Runs validations and saves.
- Raises record not found if doesnt exist.

More info about updating attributes https://zaiste.net/posts/rails-activerecord-updating-attributes-object-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Another one-line alternative:

```
Item.first.update({:popularity => "1"})
```